# Andord in-app billing: How to get google play currency exchange rate?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api

We have in-app billing and we have different prices for several countries. GetSkuDetails returns us items price in local currency, but we want to know what was the price in USD. 
We can convert currency, but what exchange rate was at the moment of purchase?

Comment: Hi Ruslan, did you find out how to do this?  I am trying to do the same thing at the moment...

Comment: Sorry, I'm late. We have used third party service (yahoo finance, if I rememeber correctely).